# Do I need to re-apply for an Indian e-tourist visa again if I'm entering India the second time already holding an e-business+e-tourist visa?

Tags: india, e-visas

I am a holder of an Indian e-visa, and on the application form I selected both the e-Tourist and the e-Business options. The ETA I received clearly states e-Business and eTourist in the Service Name field.

A few weeks ago I entered India for business purposes, but I will soon be visiting India again this time for tourism. My visa will still be valid by the time I enter, but do I have to re-apply for an e-visa with e-Tourist as the sole service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that your visa was approved for both Tourist and Business categories does not mean that you can enter once for each of those categories - it means that for any entries you are able to partake in tourist and/or business activities.

The number of times you can use your visa will depend on the details of the visa that was issued.

Most Indian e-visas's are "Double" entry, which means that you are allowed enter the country twice using the same visa.  If you check your approval there should be a heading "Entry type" that is either "Single" (only one entry allowed), "Double" (up to 2 entries allowed) or "Multiple" (any number of entries allowed").

Presuming your visa is either "Double" or "Multiple" then you're good to re-enter a second time within the expiry of your visa.